# Access TransferSpreadsheet Excel - Prevent Duplicates?

Tags: excel, ms-access, duplicates, import-from-excel

I am working on an application where there is a desire to automate data entry as much as possible.  The wish is to add a button to such entry forms for choosing an excel file to import.  I have done this for one interface, and now I'm working on others.  I'm looking for the best way to prevent duplicates are imported into a table.  For the one I am working on now, it is a simple 2 column import.  One method I have used before is to import the spreadsheet into a temp table.  Then I can utilize a query to insert where <> .  I just wonder if this is the best method to use.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. I can tailor it more if you list some more details of your projects.

From "External Data" on the ribbon, link to the excel file.

Then write the following query:

```
INSERT INTO table1
( 
field1, 
field2
)
SELECT 
a.field1, 
a.field2
FROM tableExcel AS a 
LEFT JOIN table1 AS b ON a.field1 = b.field1
WHERE (((a.field1) Is Null));
```

Then just attach a macro to the button running the query above.

Comment: I'm not sure my post explained my intent well.  This is an application.  I need to automate this.  I know how to write an insert from a table to a table.  I wanted to do it seemlessly from a spreadsheet using transferspreadsheet command.  I have an answer, which I will post separately.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the solution that will work best.  I can put an index on the 2 fields that are getting imported from the spreadsheet, into the table.  Then before I issue the transferspreadsheet command, I will set warnings false, and set them true once it is done.  This way, the user won't get errors for the indexes doing their job of rejecting duplicates.

Anyone see any problem with that solution?  The only bummer is that if I imported to a temp table, I could get a count of items first and verify the count after insert, so I could report some info to the user in the process.  Other than that, this means I don't need a temp table, and I can go directly into the goal table without worry about importing dupes.